# Как подключиться к sqlite3 только в одном файле, а использовать в других python

Tags: python, sqlite3, python-import

У меня есть Python программа, она использует базу данных sqlite3. Есть главный файл и несколько вторичных. Я могу как-нибудь подключиться к базе данных только в главном файле, а в других просто импортировать из него переменную с соединением и курсором, не писать в каждом файле `import sqlite3`?

Comment: Ну `import главный_файл` например?

Comment: Лучше даже наверное from main import ***